# Unable to see spark driver logs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I  can see all the workers logs is spark UI. However, I am unable to see the driver logs. There's no link to the driver logs even as in the below screenshot. do I need to change certain configurations to see the driver logs? ... Thanks!
[image]